# Pandas Dataframe from Dict key and list of values to have same key for multiple rows

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have created a dictionary by:

```
test_df = {}
for row in df.iterrows():
    y = []
    for x in row[1]:
        y.append(x)
    test_df[y[0]] = y[1:]
```

So my dict looks like this:

```
{'City': ['Item1',
  'Item2',
  'Item3',
  'Item4',
  'Item5']}
```

I can't seem to get a dataframe that looks like this:

```
A       B
'City'  'Item1'
'City'  'Item2'
'City'  'Item3'
'City'  'Item4'
'City'  'Item5'
```

I want to have the dictionary key be in each row for every item in the list its associated with. I've tried making two series and concat them but it didn't work. I must be over thinking this. Thanks in advance for any insight.

So BrenBarn got me onto the right path so I did the following:

```
x = [item[0] for item in test_df.items()]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': x[0], 'B': test_df[x[0]]})
for row in x[1:]:
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': row, 'B': test_df[row]})
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

It worked beautifully. Thanks guys.

Comment: Do you specifically need to support that dict format?  If you're creating the dict yourself, why don't you just create it with a structure that more closely matches the DataFrame structure you want?

Comment: my original csv file was rows like: Column A: 'City' Column B: 'Item1' Column C: 'Item2' Column D: 'Item3' Column E: 'Item4' Column F: 'Item5'             how would it be easier to create that dataframe?

Comment: Please post a sample of your original csv. Does it have more than one line? Are there the same number of items on each line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one simple way:

```
>>> pandas.DataFrame({"A": 'City', "B": d['City']})
      A      B
0  City  Item1
1  City  Item2
2  City  Item3
3  City  Item4
4  City  Item5
```

Comment: I tried to do pd.DataFrame({'A': [x for x in new_df.items()[0], 'B': new_df.items()}) but that gave me error of arrays must be all same length. If each key in the dictionary is a different city, how could I define that?

Comment: @nahata5: Please edit your question to show an actual example of what you want to do.